# Burninate: [models]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Tag [models](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/models) has 23 questions. None of them are related to any common definition of models that I am familiar with. There appears to be no common thread between them.

Further, Code Review is not about reviewing Models, but about reviewing the code that implements them.

If there was a question about code that builds or processes some 'model' then it would be different, but none of the 23 match that statement either.

There are some questions that are tagged with other frameworks (e.g. [mvc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mvc)) and those seem like much better tags.

Other questions may best be solved by changing the [models](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/models) to [best-practice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practice).

Here are some of the questions I thought may most represent the tag though (though I think some of those should be closed as off-topic anyway):

- [Models in .NET: separate settings](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26184/models-in-net-separate-settings)
- [Data model with validation in haskell couple convoluted functions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21126/data-model-with-validation-in-haskell-couple-convoluted-functions)
- [How can I improve my PHP model for my HTML5/JS mobile app?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15400/semi-repost-how-can-i-improve-my-php-model-for-my-html5-js-mobile-app)
- [how to filter (search) a model with multiple params in hash](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/500/how-to-filter-search-a-model-with-multiple-params-in-hash)
- [Critique My Codeigniter Custom CMS Pages Model](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48/critique-my-codeigniter-custom-cms-pages-model)

Burninate?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[models](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/models) has been ***burninated!***

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'd agree. The [models] tag has no description/definition so it's not clear what it means: it might as well be called [code].

Answer (score 2):

I also agree.  Usually questions tagged with this are asking about higher-level programming, and these questions get closed as off-topic/migrated to Programmers.SE.

### Burninate!